# Elasticsearch - How to find docs that contain the exact specified terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get docs that contain the exact specified terms. Terms query doesn't match because it also returns docs with additional terms.

Create index :

```
PUT my-index
{
   "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "my-field" : {
           "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Index a document:

```
PUT my-index/_doc/1
{
   "my-field": ["A", "B"]
}
```

Index another document:

```
PUT my-index/_doc/2
{
   "my-field": ["A", "B", "C"]
}
```

Use the terms query to find documents that containing A and B:

```
GET my-index/_search?pretty
{
   "query":
   {
      "terms": {
         "my-field": ["A", "B"]
      }
   }
}
```

Results :

```
{
  "took" : 178,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my-index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "my-field" : [
            "A",
            "B"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my-index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "my-field" : [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Elastic returns document 2 and document 1 because both contain A and B in my-field. It is the expected behavior, but I'd like to return only documents containing strictly A and B (if a doc contains A and B and C then it should be excluded from the results).

I've read the documentation (filters, aggregations, ...) but I can't find a way.

Thanks in advance for your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will be a tricky solution but you may use the script for this :

```
GET my-index/_search?pretty
{
   "query": {
     "bool": {
       "must": [
         {
           "terms": {
               "my-field": ["A", "B"]
            }
         },
         {
           "script": {
             "script": "doc['my-field'].size() === 2"
           }
         }
       ]
     }  
   }
}
```

You need to specify the number of the terms inside the script. For example, you need to change script as `doc['my-field'].size() === 3` if you have 3 term on the query.